# How can I implement delegation for a view controller presented by a segue?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, segue

In my main view controller, an NSTimer calls the function below after a specified delay:

```
-(void)showAdView{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowAdSegue" sender:nil];        
}
```

This modally presents `MyAdViewController`, and I'd like the `MyAdViewController` class to have a `MyAdViewControllerDelegate` protocol, so that I can implement an `adViewDidFinish` function in my main view controller.

Is it possible to do that without creating a new instance of `MyAdViewController` in the main view controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender { 
  [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self]; 
}
```

For this to work you have to include your view controller header file in the view controller executing the segue and also make the delegate property of your `MyAdViewController` public by adding it to the header file of the class.